# How to force an HBase table to a region server

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have 2 Hbase tables and I want to force each of them to a different region server. Is there a way to tell HBase to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can move a region to another region server using hbase shell move command:

```
hbase> move ‘ENCODED_REGIONNAME’, ‘SERVER_NAME’
```

> Move a region. Optionally specify target regionserver else we choose
>   one at random. NOTE: You pass the encoded region name, not the region
>   name so this command is a little different to the others. The encoded
>   region name is the hash suffix on region names: e.g. if the region
>   name were
>   TestTable,0094429456,1289497600452.527db22f95c8a9e0116f0cc13c680396.
>   then the encoded region name portion is
>   527db22f95c8a9e0116f0cc13c680396 A server name is its host, port plus
>   startcode. For example: host187.example.com,60020,1289493121758

More shell commands [here](https://learnhbase.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/hbase-shell-commands/)

Though if both tables are large they can have regions on every RegionServer in a cluster, so I'm not sure what you are going to accomplish with that.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will lose data locality in the process. HBase data is local when it is written, but when a region is moved, it is not local until major compaction occurs. So this might be something to consider prior to moving your Regions